# PHP PDO, connection works buy query not executing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am new to PDO.

Here is what i have done so far,

Created file "pdotest.php"

Code Inside that file

```
<?php

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=houserentsystem;charset=utf8', 'root', 'admin');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT roomName FROM roomName.roomnames");
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->closeCursor();
print_r($results);
var_dump($results);
```

it should display some results from database but instead it says 500 internal server error in firebug, but no error on screen, its a white blank screen.

Comment: have you tested your query? `roomName.roomnames` can't be a `MySQL` table-name afaik. plus - if you turn on exception mode, then you can't see thrown exceptions when you don't catch them. so put another `try {} catch(){}` around your `PDO` query code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT roomName FROM roomName.roomnames");
```

try this instead:

```
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT roomName FROM roomnames");
```

The select syntax is (basically):

```
SELECT column[, another_column, ...] FROM tablename[WHERE condition][ORDER BY some_column ASC/DESC];`
```

As you are setting the error mode to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, you'll need to use try/catch to see any errors. This brings the burden of wrapping `try`/`catch` statements around your db queries.

Check your php log file for the exact php error - a white screen is shown as php is probably set up not to display errors on screen.

Comment: i chaged `roomName.roomnames` to `roomnames`. it worked, Many Thanks.
but plz explain why it didnt worked when i specified tablename with it?? it is perfectly fine query tableName.columnName, why PDO didnt worked on that.

Comment: your column is roomName. Your table is roomnames. As per the SELECT syntax above, it's `SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLENAME` which gives `select roomName from roomNames'. Please select this as the answer if this has fixed your problem.

Comment: please also add to your answer that he is missing the `try` `catch` around his query code. otherwise he will not see any errors caused by his query, because he has set `PDO` errormode to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check this part:

```
SELECT roomName FROM roomName.roomnames
```

Are you really trying to select roomName column from a table named roomName.roomnames? Should it not be the other way around like

```
SELECT roomnames FROM roomName
```

?